# How to change 'No Privileges' for phpMyAdmin online?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel, directadmin

[image: nop]

I have a website I uploaded online. It works perfectly fine on XAMPP (localhost), but when online, it seems that functions like INSERTING new users to the DB (to register) do not work online, as well as many other INSERT functions. I gave all privileges on DirectAdmin, but on phpMyAdmin I still get "No Privileges".

Does anybody have a fix? and also, is it the phpMyAdmin blocking me from registering new users, or is the problem something else?

Comment: not sure what you are doing.. i have a feeling now you are creating `mysql.user` table users with `CREATE USER` for web application users? Why would you otherwise start over no privileges as most shared webhosters only allow one MySQL user per account .. Ideally you should post PHP code and your MySQL table structure as required by the [stackoverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here, the most pressing is the **lack of information**.

phpMyAdmin runs on a web server, but it looks like you are using XAMPP, which is a pre-rolled solution for users that might not necessarily know how to configure phpMyAdmin in Linux/Mac/Windows, setup their own solution, or want something easy to deploy.  There should be a log file you can grab.

I've never used XAMPP, but I have used phpMyAdmin for decades.  Setting up using the default settings XAMPP is installed to "C:\XAMPP".

If I browse to that file I see a directory called "apache" and inside that "logs".  This file, "error", should contain the error that will help us determine why your server is having issues with permissions.

**

> Please send the text from the error file in
>   "\apache\logs".

**

This might be a bug with XAMPP, phpMyAdmin, your configuration, or something else.  Paste the errors from the log file and I will be happy to look at them.  I can't solve your problem with the information you have provided, but hopefully this will help point you in the right direction.